# update regex to search for multiple strings

Tags: python

I have the following line for which I am searching for the word "Bluetooth",now I want to  search for multiple strings namely Bluetooth,MAP,FTP..how to update the regex to do this?

```
line = 'Bluetooth: Merging two BT process into one BT process to reduce memory. This patch enables BTC , MAP , FTP & SAP modules to run in com.android.bluetooth context.'
m = re.search('\nBluetooth: (.*)\n', line, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Answer (score 1):

does `m = re.search('\n(Bluetooth:|MAP|FTP) (.*)\n', line, re.IGNORECASE)`work?

**Edit**: i didnt notice the entire sample string above. Now I'm beginning to think you mean you want to match a string that starts with "Bluetooth:" and then contains either 'MAP' or 'FTP'?

if that is the case something like this:
`\nBluetooth:(.*)(MAP|FTP)(.*)\n`

I'm not understanding what exactly you are trying to accomplish. Could you explain?

Comment: From the example sentence it looks like the colon might need to be moved into the parens like `\n(Bluetooth:|MAP|FTP)` but otherwise this looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

in the re module you can use the findall method which will return a list of matched strings

```
import re
line = 'Bluetooth: Merging two BT process into one BT process to reduce memory. This patch     enables BTC , MAP , FTP & SAP modules to run in com.android.bluetooth context.'
m = re.findall('bluetooth|map|ftp', line, re.IGNORECASE)
print m
```

However I'm not sure this is what you want since this matches the laster bluetooth as well (because of the re.ignorecase). If you want a case sensitive search then this should work:

```
import re
line = 'Bluetooth: Merging two BT process into one BT process to reduce memory. This patch     enables BTC , MAP , FTP & SAP modules to run in com.android.bluetooth context.'
m = re.findall('Bluetooth|MAP|FTP', line)
print m
```

Hope that helps some.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test a your pattern (Bluetooth,MAP,FTP..) whether or not exist in a multiple string you could use this re.search, the return value will be a MatchObject when it find a match otherwise will be None

```
re.search('^(Bluetooth|MAP|FTP):.+$', s, re.IGNORECASE|re.M)
```

if you want to find all the lines match your pattern you could use

```
ret = re.findall('^((Bluetooth|MAP|FTP):.+$)', s, re.IGNORECASE|re.M)
```

or

```
re.finditer('^((Bluetooth|MAP|FTP):.+$)', s, re.IGNORECASE|re.M)
```

The difference is findall will return a list of tuple and the finditer will return a MatchObject foreach yeild.

Here is the test code for three of this method base on your request

```
>>> s = '\nBluetooth: Merging two BT process into one BT process to reduce memory. This patch enables BTC , MAP , FTP & SAP modules to run in com.android.bluetooth context.\nBluetooth: Merging two BT process into one BT process to reduce memory. This patch enables BTC , MAP , FTP & SAP modules to run in com.android.bluetooth context.\nBluetooth: Merging two BT process into one BT process to reduce memory. This patch enables BTC , MAP , FTP & SAP modules to run in com.android.bluetooth context.\n\nMerging two BT process into one BT process to reduce memory. This patch enables BTC , MAP , FTP & SAP modules to run in com.android.bluetooth context.\n'
>>> ret = re.search('^(Bluetooth|MAP|FTP):.+$', s, re.IGNORECASE|re.M)
>>> ret.groups()
('Bluetooth',)
>>> ret = re.findall('^((Bluetooth|MAP|FTP):.+$)', s, re.IGNORECASE|re.M)
>>> ret
[('Bluetooth: Merging two BT process into one BT process to reduce memory. This patch enables BTC , MAP , FTP & SAP modules to run in com.android.bluetooth context.', 'Bluetooth'), ('Bluetooth: Merging two BT process into one BT process to reduce memory. This patch enables BTC , MAP , FTP & SAP modules to run in com.android.bluetooth context.', 'Bluetooth'), ('Bluetooth: Merging two BT process into one BT process to reduce memory. This patch enables BTC , MAP , FTP & SAP modules to run in com.android.bluetooth context.', 'Bluetooth')]
>>> for m in re.finditer('^((Bluetooth|MAP|FTP):.+$)', s, re.IGNORECASE|re.M):
...     if m:
...         print(m.group())
...         
Bluetooth: Merging two BT process into one BT process to reduce memory. This patch enables BTC , MAP , FTP & SAP modules to run in com.android.bluetooth context.
Bluetooth: Merging two BT process into one BT process to reduce memory. This patch enables BTC , MAP , FTP & SAP modules to run in com.android.bluetooth context.
Bluetooth: Merging two BT process into one BT process to reduce memory. This patch enables BTC , MAP , FTP & SAP modules to run in com.android.bluetooth context.
>>> for m in re.finditer('^((Bluetooth|MAP|FTP):.+$)', s, re.IGNORECASE|re.M):
...     if m:
...         print(m.groups())
...         
('Bluetooth: Merging two BT process into one BT process to reduce memory. This patch enables BTC , MAP , FTP & SAP modules to run in com.android.bluetooth context.', 'Bluetooth')
('Bluetooth: Merging two BT process into one BT process to reduce memory. This patch enables BTC , MAP , FTP & SAP modules to run in com.android.bluetooth context.', 'Bluetooth')
('Bluetooth: Merging two BT process into one BT process to reduce memory. This patch enables BTC , MAP , FTP & SAP modules to run in com.android.bluetooth context.', 'Bluetooth')
```